# How can I access named custom instance attributes generated with Geometry Nodes in Python?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, instances, custom-attributes

I have a question. How can I access named custom instance attributes generated with Geometry Nodes in Python?

What I did:

1. I set up named custom instance attribute with Geometry Nodes, named "Color"
2. I confirmed that it's set expectedly in the Spread sheet
3. I tried to access the "Color" instance attribute in python but I couldn't find the attribute

[image: screenshot of setting up custon instance attribute with Geometry nodes]

I iterated through evaluated instance objects, but I couldn't find.

```
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
for object_instance in depsgraph.object_instances:
    if object_instance.is_instance:
        for attr in dir(object_instance):
            print(str(attr), getattr(object_instance, attr))
        for attr in dir(object_instance.instance_object):
            print(str(attr), getattr(object_instance.instance_object, attr))
        for attr in dir(object_instance.object):
            print(str(attr), getattr(object_instance.object, attr))
        for attr in dir(object_instance.object.data):
            print(str(attr), getattr(object_instance.object.data, attr))
```

I thought it could be in `object_instance.object.data.attributes`, but it isn't in.

```
print(object_instance.object.data.attributes.keys())
["material_index", "uv_map"]
```

I'm happy if someone tells me how to access them.

Blender version: 3.3.1
OS: Windows 10

Comment: I'm interested in this too. As far as I get this attribute isn't in Object.data. It's somewhere in Object or ObjectInstance itself.

Comment: I just stick it here. https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/k75r/?sorting=hot

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved the problem by storing the attribute `Color` on both the points and the instances created from the points and using `Join Geometry`.

Like this the `Color` attribute is accessible from the evaluated obj with `obj_eval.data.attributes["Color"]`.