Get spline parameter length of a curve using python
I have a bezier curve and I want to get the length of every segment. I can use bpy.context.object.data.splines.active.calc_length() to get the total length of the curve but couldn't figure put a way to do this for every segment. If I apply a geo nodes modifier to the curve and see the spline parameter length I can see the exact data I need in the spreadsheet. Is there a way for me to get this out of blender like a csv or print to console?


Not sure if it will work, but worth trying: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279992/how-can-i-access-named-custom-instance-attributes-generated-with-geometry-nodes (to be sure, you can convert curve to mesh with very low resolution in case python doesn't see attributes for curve points)

Thanks, will check it out.

You could try creating a temp spline, then use the 2 handles you're interested in with active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].co to create the 2 points, measure that new spline with calc_length() delete new spline, rinse and repeat?
See this for a bit more fun: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191933/how-can-i-get-position-and-type-of-handle-in-bezier-curve
